# Prove that $1 + 4 + 9 ... + n^2 = (n/6)(n+1)(2n+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that it is true but not sure how to write the proof for: $1 + 4 + 9 ... + n^2 = (n/6)(n+1)(2n+1)$. I need help to guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

**edit:**

Okay at n=k I have $ 1+4+9 ... + k^2 = (k/6)(k+1)(2k+1)$

and at $n=k+1$ I have $((k+1)/6))((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1) = ((k+1)/6)(k+2)(2k+3).$

Does my base step need to begin at $n=0$ or $n=1?$ How do I tell?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried?

Comment: Well first I'm trying to figure out if I this is something I can prove by induction. For instance is it necessary to have a base step, the assumption, and the n+1 step in this proof? @PaulSundheim

Comment: In the second proof below, assume that the theorem is true for some $n=k$.  The rest of the proof works fine though.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n=1$, it is Okay.

Suppose that $n=k$, $$1 + 4 + 9 \cdots + k^2 = (k/6)(k+1)(2k+1).$$
Then $n=k+1$,  $$1 + 4 + 9 \cdots + k^2+(k+1)^2 = (k/6)(k+1)(2k+1)+(k+1)^2=((k+1)/6)(k+2)(2k+3).$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1$,

and then sum it from 1 to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by picture $%random text fdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfs$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer from U of Manitoba at the following link: [**Link to proof**](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~thomas/Courses/textS1-21.pdf)

In the future, type your problem in Google Search to see if the solution is out there already. Odds are, the answer to your question is already there. I found it with ease typing $1 + 4 + 9 … + n^2 = (n/6)(n+1)(2n+1)$ in Google Search.